# Why every $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ is the solution of some ${\bf a}^\text{T}{\bf x}=b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $\Bbb R^n$. A $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ is called a hyperplane. It is easy to see an equation ${\bf a}^\text{T}{\bf x}=b$ defines a hyperplane, because the solution space is the null space of ${\bf A}=({\bf{a}},{\bf 0},...,{\bf 0})^{\text T}$ (i.e. the solution space of ${\bf a}^\text{T}{\bf x}={\bf 0}$) plus a particular solution of ${\bf a}^\text{T}{\bf x}=b$ (which can be interpreted as a translation).

However, I am puzzled if every hyperplane $H\subset \Bbb R^n$ is a solution space of some ${\bf a}^\text{T}{\bf x}=b$, and how do we find the corresponding $\bf a$ and $ b$. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_1, \dots, v_{n-1}$ be a basis of the linear space associated to $H$, and consider the matrix $P$ whose rows are the vectors $v_i$. The kernel of $P$ is one dimensional and contains a non-zero vector $n$ that is orthogonal to $\text{span}\{v_i\}$. Letting $b$ be any point on $H$, you find that the equation of $H$ is
$$
n^T x = n^Tb.
$$

**Note:** The linear space associated to $H$ is the linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is parallel to $H$.